# Setting a counter using prime faces

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have an application for searching a place in a particular locality and set a counter for each and every place to generate a statistic report (in the form of a graph). The report is based on number of hits  .  I am not interested in having a separate table to save the counter . Is there any alternative way to handle this scenario ....

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to have a separate table - do you mean a table in the database? (very vague formulated question, but I think I know what you mean). If so, add a numeric field of your choise to your `Locality` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Locality {
  private String name;
  private int counter;
  public voidincreaseCounter() {
    counter++;
  }
  public int getCounter() {
    return this.counter;
  }
}
```

... and when the search has happened increase the counter from that locality:

```
public void searchPerformed(String searchString) {
  String locality = ....// parse the search string
  Locality locality = localityRepository.getLocality(localityName);
  if (locality == null) {
    locality = new Locality(localityName);
  }
  locality.increaseCounter();
  System.out.println("New counter for " + locality + ": " + locality.getCounter());
  localityRepository.update(locality);
}
```

Comment: I'm not forcing you, but you might as well accept the answer. If another person has the same problem, they know instantly which answer contained the solution. In this case there is just one answer, but if there would be more it could be quite difficult to find the "correct" one, which helped the most/solved the problem. If you are not sure how this works [check this out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)